# Inverting a complex shape in an SVG file

Tags: svg

I have an SVG file that I would like changed.

[image]

Rather than showing all the background I need it to show the letters and the boat.  Would that be called inverting? And how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Inverting only changes the places of foreground and background colors. You want to create new shapes which cover some white areas of your image. Obviously you also want some other new shapes made of the black areas. You can create and color them in a vector editor program. I recommend Illustrator due its precisely working area filling tools. It's like filling areas in Photoshop, but as vectors without any bitmap coarseness.

Close the gap at the top left corner of A with a new black shape in Illustrator. Then fill interesting  areas with the Shape Builder or Live Paint tool. You will get perfectly fitting new vector shapes, which can get arbitary fill colors and strokes.

Shape builder is easier to learn and the result is immediate, no need to fix the effect by expanding before selecting the new colors.

I tried the same for your screenshot in Photoshop. Of course it's only a low resolution bitmap with random colors with no deeper idea:

[image]